# How to cancel this js function

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function()
    {
        var el=document.getElementById('affiliate_0');
        el.onclick=function(){
            var my_text=prompt('Enter: Name - Email');
            if(my_text)     
                window.open("http://affiliateaddress&subid1="+my_text)
        }

        var el2=document.getElementById('affiliate_1');
        el2.onclick=function(){
            var my_text=prompt('Enter: Name - Email');
            if(my_text)
                window.open("http://affiliateaddress="+my_text)
        }
    }
</script>
```

This function gets through even when the user presses cancel. I do not want that. Please help.

Comment: What do those elements look like in the HTML?

Comment: They are image buttons

Comment: when they press cancel, all theyre doing is not running the `window.open` code.. what do you mean?

Comment: No. After the prompt comes up, some users press cancel and the function lets them visit the website. I do not want that. I want the function to end when the user presses enter. I want the prompt box to simply go away without changing the url

Comment: hi just use if(my_text !=null){   ... }

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It works.
http://jsfiddle.net/qq0bad21/
When you press cancel, prompt returns null. When you press enter without a value, it returns "" which evaluates to false too.